# How to search records by dropdownlist using asp.net

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, vb.net

how to search records from dropdown list using asp.net and from that record I should open the table how the data is stored.
For example: If I click avinash in dropdown list it should display what the data stored with avinash then I should open the link of avinash then it should go to another table how the data has been stored. Here is the code for the dropdown list.

```
     <tr>
        <td style="width:120px;text-align:top" class="blue">OwnerDepartment:</td>
         <td class="auto-style9"><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOwnerDepartment" runat="server"
             onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                                                  </asp:DropDownList>
                          </td>
     </tr>
```

and the view code for dropdownlist in aspx.vb

```
Private Sub DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ddlOwnerDepartment.SelectedValue = DropdownList.SelectedItem.Value
End Sub
```

can anyone help me to fix this code and how to link to next table.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Some clarification required *It should display what the data stored with avinash?* Here you want to get particular record of the person you have choose.  *It should go to another table how the data has been stored* please clarify what table are we talking about.

Comment: @suprabhat hello can I have update on this??

Comment: Here when you select the name from dropdown you can get the id of the person whose records need to be edited and save in a hiddenfield, then when click on the button before you redirect to `addregistration,aspx` page you can get the value from hidden field and pass it as a querystring like `addregistration,aspx?id=10` for e.g from in addregistration page you can read the querystring if it contains any value. If exists then get the data related to this id and then one by one populate all fields :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can follow this link may be it will help

http://forums.asp.net/t/1859410.aspx?Search+record+with+Dropdown+list+and+text+box+